# Convert String in EditText to Double

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I wanted to make a little app.
What this app is supposed to do is have a running "bank account" total and there are two options: deposit money or withdraw money.
I attached the main activity class as well as the class I made for the "bank account" (I haven't implemented the history function yet as I have not figure out this part!).
Basically, this line:

```
bankAccount.withdrawal(Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.inputWithdrawal).toString()))
```

and it's deposit counterpart is throwing a *`NumberFormatException`* saying it's an "Invalid Double".
I have no Idea what I've look on other threads but ihavent been able to find anything that works.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;   
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText withdrawal, deposit;
    private Button withdrawalButton, depositButton;
    private BankAccount bankAccount;
    private String total;
    private TextView textViewTotal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        withdrawal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWithdrawal);
        deposit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDeposit);

        withdrawalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.withdrawalButton);
        depositButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.depositButton);
        withdrawalButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        depositButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        bankAccount = new BankAccount();
        textViewTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total);
        updateTotal();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            try {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.withdrawalButton:
                        if (!withdrawal.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            bankAccount.withdrawal(Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.inputWithdrawal).toString()));
                            updateTotal();
                        }
                        break;

                    case R.id.depositButton:
                        if (!deposit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            bankAccount.deposit(Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.inputDeposit).toString()));
                            updateTotal();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }};

    public void updateTotal(){
        total = "$" + bankAccount.getCheckingTotal();
        textViewTotal.setText(total);
    }  
}
```

```
public class BankAccount {
    private double checkingTotal;
    private ArrayList<String> history;

    public BankAccount(){
        checkingTotal = 0;
        history = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void withdrawal(double amount){
        checkingTotal -= amount;
        history.add("-$" + amount);

        if(history.size() > 5)
            history.remove(0);
    }

    public void deposit(double amount){
        checkingTotal += amount;
        history.add("$" + amount);

        if(history.size() > 5)
            history.remove(0);
    }

    public double getCheckingTotal(){
        return checkingTotal;
    }
}
```

Comment: read the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findViewById(R.id.inputWithdrawal)` returns a `View`

`View.toString()` gives you some garbage value (not the content of the `EditText`).

You *already have* `withdrawal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWithdrawal);`, so use it to get the String (like you **already did** with `getText().toString()` to see if the string was empty).

```
String w = withdrawal.getText().toString();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(w)) {
    bankAccount.withdrawal(Double.parseDouble(w));
    updateTotal();
}
```

Tip: always avoid extra `findViewById` calls.